# Tapped cell in UITableView returns label text from last cell out of an array not the chosen one

Tags: ios, swift

I have fixed my earlier problem and have now worked out where the main problem is, I am pulling in a json array with alamofire but am not sure how to properly move the data from one viewcontroller to another. If I hardcode the array with var name = ["Hello", "Goodbye"] I can get it to work but am not sure how to do it with the json. Thank you to any and all help.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



    let URL_GET_DATA = "http://www.localnewsplus.com.au/ios/service.php"

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeroes: UITableView!

    var heroes = [Hero]()

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return heroes.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        let hero: Hero
        hero = heroes[indexPath.row]

        cell.labelName.text = hero.name
        cell.labelTeam.text = hero.team

        Alamofire.request(hero.imageUrl!).responseImage { response in

            if let image = response.result.value {
                cell.heroImage.image = image
            }
        }

        //cell.labelName.text = name[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(URL_GET_DATA).responseJSON { response in

            if let json = response.result.value {

                let heroesArray : NSArray  = json as! NSArray

                for i in 0..<heroesArray.count{

                    self.heroes.append(Hero(
                        name: (heroesArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "st_heading") as? String,
                        team: (heroesArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "st_modified") as? String,
                        imageUrl: (heroesArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "imageurl") as? String
                    ))

                }

                self.tableViewHeroes.reloadData()
            }

        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "articleViewController") as? articleViewController
        vc?.article_st_heading = name[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this

1. Try to get data from the array which you used in cellForRow to populate data

> Let text = someArray[indexPath. Row]

2. Get the cell instead of the create new one in didSelect method

> Let cell = table. CellForRowAt[indexPath ]
>
> ```
> Let text = cell.text
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your help Krimi. I tried your suggestion with let text = cell?.article_st_heading but am now getting a warning with Initialization of immutable value 'text' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it.

Comment: The warning is indicating you the constant text you declare is not use in your code. So either use it or replace it with _. Now Debug the code with break point and check that do you get the text in above mentioned line?